# How to delete a column of a table after pasting it from another workbook automatically using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently copying a table from another workbook by using ***CurrentRegion***, however, I do not need column F, but it would not work if I used ***CurrentRegion*** as it will take the whole table. Is there any way to copy the table without column F and shift the rest (which is column G) to left? I declare **x** as the source worksheet and **y** is the destination workbook.
`x.Worksheets("week10_a1").Range("A9").CurrentRegion.Copy
y.Worksheets("A1").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

How do i delete column F of the table before pasting it to the destination workbook or how do i delete column J of the table after pasting it to the destination workbook without affecting the previous table in the destination workbook?
[Source workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MZ85.png)

[Destination workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5ndj.png)

Answer (score 0):

This code will select the region and exclude column F from selection and copy it. Once you paste it, it will remain without what was originally in column F.

```
Worksheets("week10_a1").Range("A9:G19").Select
Dim areaToCopy, cell As Range
Set areaToCopy = Nothing
For Each cell In Selection
  If Intersect(cell, Range("F:F")) Is Nothing Then
    If areaToCopy Is Nothing Then ' prevent Union to throw error
      Set areaToCopy = cell
    Else
      Set areaToCopy = Union(areaToCopy, cell)
    End If
  End If
Next cell
areaToCopy.Copy
```

Comment: Hi, I am sorry as i am very new to VBA. I've tried but then it displays error on line `x.Worksheets("week10_a1").Range("A9").CurrentRegion.Select`. 
The error is Run-time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed.

Comment: @mmaz sorry, edited my answer. now it will select the table i saw on your screenshot. you can edit the range as you want.

Comment: It still displaying  error on  line 'x.Worksheets("week10_a1").Range("A9:G19").Select'. However, my table size may not be constant every week so i cannot use Range("A9:G19"). Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: @mmaz I used first line from your post so I expected it to work. Ok another update. Reading size of table is another question, you will have to create new question for that one.